# How to I print a list in Python in a different format?

Tags: python

My list looks like this:

```
food_order = ['Spicy Chicken Sandwich', 'Chick-fil-A Waffle Potato Fries', 'Chic-fil-A Lemonade', 'Chocolate Chunk Cookie']
```

and I would like for it to look like:

```
Spicy Chicken Sandwich

Chick-fil-A Waffle PotatoFries

Chic-fil-A Lemonade

Chocolate Chunk Cookie
```

Comment: That's not a dictionary (it's a `list`), and you're basically asking how to use a `for` loop and `print` (or maybe `join` and `print`). If you don't know how to do this, you have so many fundamental things to learn it's not practical for you to learn them piecemeal with questions here. Run through a tutorial in its entirety, or talk to your teacher.

Comment: I meant list, my bad. I have been working all day and am getting my terms  mixed up

Answer (score 1):

As simple as:

```
for x in food_order:
  print(x)
```

Or if you want to print a new line after every item:

```
for x in food_order:
  print(x+"\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) a list with new lines and print it:

```
food_order = ['Spicy Chicken Sandwich', 'Chick-fil-A Waffle Potato Fries', 'Chic-fil-A Lemonade', 'Chocolate Chunk Cookie']

print('\n\n'.join(food_order))
```

This will stick two new line characters between each of your list items and make a new string.

Result:

```
Spicy Chicken Sandwich

Chick-fil-A Waffle Potato Fries

Chic-fil-A Lemonade

Chocolate Chunk Cookie
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score -1):

Code:

```py
food_order = ['Spicy Chicken Sandwich', 'Chick-fil-A Waffle Potato Fries',
              'Chic-fil-A Lemonade', 'Chocolate Chunk Cookie']
for food in food_order:
    print(food)
    print('\n')
```

Output:

```
Spicy Chicken Sandwich

Chick-fil-A Waffle Potato Fries

Chic-fil-A Lemonade

Chocolate Chunk Cookie
```

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)